# Adding integer to a list using append and for loop in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, append, args

I am new to python stuck with the issue of not getting the list after appending using the *args to fetch every element.

```
def has_33(*args):
    m=[]
    for i in args:
        m = m.append(i)
    print(m)
has_33([1,3,3])
```

output

```
None
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```py
def has_33(*args):
    m=list(args)
    print(m)
has_33([1,3,3])
```

And if you don't need the list you can do this:

```py
def has_33(*args):
    m=list(args)
    n = []
    for l in m:
        for elem in l:
            n.append(elem)

    print(n)
has_33([1,3,3])
```

Comment: Any reason why the above coding is not fetching the elements

Comment: @SagarDixit It's because `append()` returns None

Comment: Output to your code:[[1, 3, 3]]

Comment: The output is `[[1, 3, 3]]`

Comment: But I don't need a nested list instead a single list

Comment: @SagarDixit Added that as well

Answer (score 1):

Remove `m=m.append(i)` and write like this   `m.append(i)`
This works.

Comment: But I am getting a nested list any ways of getting a single list

Comment: Yes,this works because m is initially a empty list and you are appending an element to that list

Comment: Remove * in the function parameter  ```has_33(args)```